# Call service from arduino?

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-kinetic, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to call a ROS service to turn on/off relays from an arduino.  The service works from the command line and also from a python service client call.  How do I call a service from an arduino?

The relay service message is:

```
int32 channel
bool  state
---
bool success
```

I made the ros_lib library and the new service is listed.

```
rosrun rosserial_client make_libraries .
```

How do you call the service?

```
#include <WProgram.h>
#include "ros.h"
#include <ros/service_client.h>
#include "turtlebot/relayCmd.h"


ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::ServiceClient<turtlebot::relayCmd::Request, turtlebot::relayCmd::Response> client("/relay_cmd");
turtlebot::relayCmd::Request relay_request;
turtlebot::relayCmd::Response response;

void setup() {
  nh.initNode();

  nh.getHardware()->setBaud(57600);

  while (!nh.connected())
  {
      nh.spinOnce();
  }
  nh.loginfo("Teensy is connected");
  delay(1);
}

void loop() {
    relay_request.channel = 2;
    relay_request.state = 1;

    response.success = false;

    nh.loginfo("Calling relay server");

    if ( client.call(relay_request, response) ) {
      nh.loginfo("service callback true");
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

Error Message during compiling:

```
   Compiling .pioenvs/teensy31/src/main.cpp.o
src/main.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
src/main.cpp:42:21: error: could not convert 'client.ros::ServiceClient<MReq, MRes>::call<turtlebot::relayCmdRequest, turtlebot::relayCmdResponse>(relay_request, response)' from 'void' to 'bool'
if ( client.call(relay_request, response) ) {
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299081/call-service-from-arduino?/) by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Followed the format on this post:
https://answers.ros.org/question/38719/ros-service-client-arduino-not-publishing/

It is working now.

---

Originally posted by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) with karma: 90 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1